# How do I check a checkbox in DOS?

Tags: ms-dos, freedos

At a certain point during the installation of FreeDOS, one has to choose which optional packages to install. The packages selected by default are marked with Xs in their repective boxes. One then has to place Xs in the boxes of the unselected packages.

[image]

I do not know how to make the Xs in the boxes. I can move between boxes with the arrow keys, but cannot find any way to make an X. I have tried to type the X. I also tried SHIFT + X, to no avail.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try Spacebar?

Comment: Thanks alot! That works. I would never have thought of it.

Comment: This question makes me happy.  Glad to see someone breaking out the old FreeDOS.

Comment: I am doing a course in assembly language. The course requires that we use DEBUG.exe. to test our programs. I use Linux. I installed FreeDOS in a virtual machine.

Comment: *> I would never have thought of it.*   `o.O` Um, why not? It’s the same in Windows.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Press Spacebar. In most UIs this performs an action on the currently selected element.